# Using JSON_VALUE to query all instance of value by key

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2017 (v14).

I need to query all `Comments` in a JSON column.

So far, I have tried this T-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
WHERE JSON_Value(raw_data, '$.Items[0].Comment') LIKE '%9644676%'     
   OR JSON_Value(raw_data, '$.Items[1].Comment') LIKE '%9644676%'
```

This works in this particular instance but the Items may have several `Comment` lines.

Is there a way to loop though all comments under `Items`?

Thanks.

Comment: please provide a full [mre] to your query see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `APPLY` the `OPENJSON` function, in other words it will generate many rows for each one of the original rows.

Use a schema on the `OPENJSON` function to get a nice table of all properties. Use a root path to jumpt straight to `Items`.

```sql
SELECT
  i.*,
  j.*
FROM invoices i
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(i.raw_data, '$.Items')
  WITH (
    Comment nvarchar(1000)
  ) j
WHERE j.Comment LIKE '%9644676%';
```

Alternatively as an `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT
  i.*
FROM invoices i
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON(i.raw_data, '$.Items')
      WITH (
        Comment nvarchar(1000)
      ) j
    WHERE j.Comment LIKE '%9644676%'
);
```